# Remove specific values from numpy array without loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy arrays:

```
# doors = [[0,1,2],[0,1,2],....,[0,1,2]
doors = np.broadcast_to(np.array([0, 1, 2]),(max_samples, 3))
# first_choice = [ [2],[1],....,[2] ]
first_choice = np.random.randint(3, size=(max_samples, 1))
```

Without using any kind of loops (for, while, etc.) i would like to create a new numpy array called result who contains doors with suppressed first choice.

Example:

```
first_choice = [ [2], [1], [1], [0] ....]
result = [ [0,1],[0,2],[0,2],[1,2] .....]
```

How can i do that ? Use of any libraries if accepted if necessary, i think numpy can do that request but don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possibility:

```
import numpy as np

max_samples = 10
np.random.seed(100)
doors = np.broadcast_to(np.array([0, 1, 2]),(max_samples, 3))
first_choice = np.random.randint(3, size=(max_samples, 1))
print(first_choice[:, 0])
# [0 0 0 2 2 0 2 1 2 2]
# Take non-matches and reshape
result = doors[doors != first_choice].reshape((-1, 2))
print(result)
# [[1 2]
#  [1 2]
#  [1 2]
#  [0 1]
#  [0 1]
#  [1 2]
#  [0 1]
#  [0 2]
#  [0 1]
#  [0 1]]
```

Obviously for this to work each value in `first_choice` must be present once (and only once) in each corresponding row of `doors`.